# J2ME на Kotlin для Android

Tags: android, j2me

Предыстория: В нашем городе есть служба такси, работники которого используют Java ME приложение, которому уже лет 15. Раньше скупали старые телефоны, и раздавали таксистам, сейчас используют эмуляторы J2ME Loader и Retro2ME. Но проблема в том что нужно обьяснить мужику лет 60и, который всю жизнь крутил баранку, как это все настроить.

Собственно ко мне обратился приятель с вопросам могу ли я что-то сделать, что бы просто дать им АПК файлик, и все заработало. Я ответил что нет, так как не имею подобного опыта, и как потом оказалось максимально далек от понимания этого. Но уже несколько вечеров копаюсь в J2ME Loader и microemu на гите, перечитал все что мог найти, но так и не понял как с минимальными потерями можно, грубо говоря, вывести контент ME приложения во View, и предоставить интерфейс для взаимодействия...

Может кто-то знает хороший, подробный материал... Буду благодарен за ссылочку на него. Спасибо.

Comment: Исходники приложения есть? Если есть, здесь инструкция для сборки APK из форка J2ME-Loader: https://github.com/woesss/JL-Mod/wiki/Porting-midlet-instruction. Скорее всего я забыл какие-то нюансы и придётся додумать самому, но для старта хватит. В проекте есть даже "Hello World" для наглядности. Без исходников, в принципе, тоже можно собрать (не знаю как на это смотрит авторское право, однако) - нужно пропатчить код ASM-ом (как это делает эмулятор) подключить jar как библиотеку и вытянуть манифест, в остальном инструкция будет схожей.

Comment: @woesss Спасибо огромное, то что нужно!